# Can I make git-svn import a Subversion repository which itself contains git repositories

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I have a project in SVN which has a plugins folder.  Several of the plugins folders are git repositories -- I added them to my plugins folder using `git clone`.

This has been working well for me but now I'm looking to migrate my SVN repository to git using `git-svn`:

```
git svn init http://path/to/my/repo --no-metadata 
git config svn.authorsfile ~/authors.txt
git svn fetch
```

This works fine for all my early revisions which didn't have the git repos in my plugins folder, but when it hits the first revision containing a git repository it fails with the following error:

```
trunk/plugins/my_plugin/.git/HEAD was not found in commit 
ae9ad0ab7cebd144c823d90d43cdab2b30d13f9e (r2259)
```

Is there a way around this to allow me to fully import my repository, perhaps by excluding any .git folders which reside in the SVN repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I was using git-svn 1.5 on Ubuntu which didn't support the `--ignore-paths` flag on `git-svn fetch`.  After building git 1.6 from source I can now run:

```
git svn fetch --ignore-paths='\.git'
```

The fetch now ignores all `.git` folders and successfully imports all the SVN history to my new git repository.

Answer (score 1):

You could dump the current svn repo, [filter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering) out the .git directories, and create another svn repo based on this filtered dump, and use this new one as a basis for the git repo.

Parallel use of git and svn would probably be *interesting* - you'd have to replace the existing repo with new gitless one, and the missing .git directories could cause some hassles.

I have not tried this, so you're going to want to be careful, and have backups.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way Git works, having more than 1 .git folder will cause you problems (well, you already know that hehe).

You have 2 options:
- if you don't care about story, do it the easy way: remove the .git folders from svn and move to git the full project

- if you care about story, do it the hard way: check this [link](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) and follow the steps

I know my team leader had some issues with that, but it works.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention another way: you might use [Bazaar](http://bazaar-vcs.org/) to pull the project, as it interacts with both. Not sure if that would be easier though